# Sequeilize find highest value of table in where clause

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a Table called Seasons where columns are "start_at" and "end_at". these columsn contain year values like 2019 and 2020 and so on. I want to update one row which has the highest value in "end_at" column.
I tried something like this:

```js
Season.update({is_current: 0}, {where: {is_current: 1}}))
.then(() => Season.update({is_current: 1}, {
    where: sequelize.where(
        sequelize.fn("MAX", sequelize.col("end_at"))
    )
}))
```

But it gives me an error:

> Error: Invalid use of group function

Can somebody help me?

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: Thats not heltping

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
Season.findOne({
    where : { is_current : 0 }, // find records which is_current = 0;
    order : [  ['end_at', 'DESC'] ] // order by desc will make highest to the first record
}).then(ref => {
    if(ref) { // <-- Check if any record exists
        ref.is_current = 1; //<--- Update Value in instance
        return ref.save(); // <-- Save to DB
    }

});
```